# mySQL Query - select join if latest record in join table contains a specific value

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to write a select statement with a right join (to clients), that will find a specific value in the join table - but ONLY if that is the most recent value for each client (ignoring blanks and nulls).

```
  Clients
  Id    Name
   0     John Doe
   1     Frank Smith
   2     Sue Smith
   3     John Smith


 Activity   (join table)
 ClientId  Type   Date
   0       500   2013-01-01 00:00:08
   1       900   2013-01-01 00:00:07
   2       NULL  2013-01-01 00:00:06
   3             2013-01-01 00:00:05
   4       500   2013-01-01 00:00:05
   0       800   2013-01-01 00:00:04
   1       500   2013-01-01 00:00:03
   2       500   2013-01-01 00:00:02
   3       500   2013-01-01 00:00:01
   4       800   2013-01-01 00:00:00
```

So this query will at least give me only the client records that have an activity type of 500 (in this case I would get back client 0 and 4):

```
select * from clients right join activity on activity.clientid = clients.id 
where activity.type = 500
```

HOWEVER, I need to figure out how to make this return ONLY the first record in the above list of records.  The logic there is Client #0 is the only client that has 500 as it's latest activity type = 500.  The other 3 clients have NULL, blank, or 900 for example as their 'latest' activity type.

I am thinking some magic with ordering (the date would normally be pretty accurate), a 'top' and/or 'limit' and possibly union?  Just cant quite wrap my head around it.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: Just FYI, LEFT JOINs outnumber RIGHT JOINs on SO by about 30 to 1. Just sayin' ;-)

Comment: You need better sample data - all of the dates are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
SELECT activity.id AS activityid
    , activity.type
    , activity.date
    , clients.id AS clientid
    , clients.name
FROM activity
LEFT JOIN activity AS other_activities
  ON activity.ClientID  = other_activities.ClientID
    AND activity.date < other_activities.date
LEFT JOIN clients
  ON activity.ClientID = clients.id
WHERE activity.type = 500
  AND other_activities.ClientID IS NULL;
```

Comment: This appears to be working, but I am finding I also need to account for a 'blank' or 'NULL' value.   So for example, if the client had a blank activity value, then a '500', I dont want to count the blank.

Comment: got it, I just added a second condition: "    AND other_activities.type > 0"   (it's actually numeric in my database)   in the left join activity!   thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the most recent Activity of type 500 and the client of that activity

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT *
     FROM activity
     WHERE type=500
     ORDER BY date DESC
     LIMIT 1) a
LEFT JOIN
     clients c
ON (a.clientid = c.id)
```

of if you only want the result if it's the most recent activity and the type is 500 you can use

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT *
     FROM activity
     ORDER BY date DESC
     LIMIT 1) a
LEFT JOIN
     clients c
ON (a.clientid = c.id)
WHERE a.type = 500;
```

[sqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c183b/4/0) to get clients who have the latest activity of type 500

```
SELECT a1.ClientID,c.name,a1.Type,a1.Date
FROM activity a1
LEFT JOIN clients c ON (c.id = a1.clientid)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM activity a
                  WHERE a.clientid = a1.clientid
                    and a.date > a1.date)
AND a1.type = 500;
```

Comment: the top query appears to return only 1 client.  the type logic seems correct, but then it's limit 1 and left join, so you only get 1 record.   I need ALL the clients that had a most recent activity of type 500.

Comment: try the very bottom query of my answer, it'll give you clients who have the latest activity of type 500

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from Activity 
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(Date) as min_date, clientID 
    FROM Activity 
    GROUP BY clientID) temp 
ON Activity.clientID = temp.clientID 
WHERE date = min_date and type = 500
```

This will return all clientID's whose most recent activity was of type 500.

Comment: This one does not appear to be working.  There are at a minimum records not in the result list that should be.